# Error in executing groovy script in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, groovy

below is my query, I want to change score calculation using function_score feature:

```
{
  "size": 1,
  "query":{
      "function_score": {
    "query": {
      "bool": {
        "must": [
          {
            "match": {
              "messageText": "car"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "script_score" : {
        "script" : "doc['time_views'].values[doc['time_views'].values.length-1]"
    }
    ,
    "boost_mode": "replace"
  }
  },
  "from": 0
}
```

but I got this error response

```
{
    "error": {
        "root_cause": [
            {
                "type": "script_exception",
                "reason": "failed to run inline script [doc['time_views'].values[doc['time_views'].values.length-1]] using lang [groovy]"
            }
        ],
        "type": "search_phase_execution_exception",
        "reason": "all shards failed",
        "phase": "query",
        "grouped": true,
        "failed_shards": [
            {
                "shard": 0,
                "index": "datacollection",
                "node": "TWeZV3R6Rq-WYQ2YIHjILQ",
                "reason": {
                    "type": "script_exception",
                    "reason": "failed to run inline script [doc['time_views'].values[doc['time_views'].values.length-1]] using lang [groovy]",
                    "caused_by": {
                        "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
                        "reason": "No field found for [time_views] in mapping with types [message]"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "status": 500
}
```

some solutions says using quotation in "doc['time_views']" causes the problem when query has been send from command prompt tools. I don't know why!
I don't use any command prompt tools. I create the query in java code directly

> EDIT

this is my index mapping:

```
"mappings": {
    "message": {
        "properties": {
            "text": {
               "type": "string"
            },
            "time_views": {
                "type": "nested",
                   "properties": {
                      "backupTimestamp": {
                         "type": "long"
                      },
                      "views": {
                         "type": "integer"
                      }
                   }
                }
             }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to use "views" of last item of "time_views". so I try below scripts too, but each of them throw different error:

```
"doc['time_views.views'].values[doc['time_views.views'].values.length-1]"

error: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.lang.Number

"doc['time_views.views'].values[doc['time_views.views'].values.size()-1]"

error: failed to run inline script [doc['time_views.views'].values[doc['time_views.views'].values.size()-1]] using lang [groovy]

"doc['time_views'].values[doc['time_views'].values.size()-1].views"

error: failed to run inline script [doc['time_views'].values[doc['time_views'].values.size()-1].views] using lang [groovy]"
```

Comment: Can you try this instead `doc.time_views.values[-1]` ? Of course the `time_views` field needs to be declared in your mapping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm really new in elasticsearch and groovy language. I didn't care about that "time_views" is nested Object, also I don't know syntax of groovy exactly, after some affort I found my mistakes and the solution:

```
{
  "size": 1,
  "query":{
      "function_score": {
    "query": {
      "bool": {
        "must": [
          {
            "match": {
              "messageText": "car"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "script_score" : {
        "script" : "doc['time_views.views'].values.get(doc['time_views.views'].values.size()-1)"
    }
    ,
    "boost_mode": "replace"
  }
  },
  "from": 0
}
```

It's work as I expected